# Не указывается путь к файлу в поле констант, как исправить? Если создать локальную переменную, то ссылка выводиться

Tags: 1с

Создать строковые константы «КаталогЗагрузки» и «ФайлЗагрузки». Создать форму констант для их заполнения из диалога выбора каталога или файла не модально.

&НаКлиенте
Процедура КаталогЗагрузкиНачалоВыбора(Элемент, ДанныеВыбора, СтандартнаяОбработка)

```
СтандартнаяОбработка = Ложь;

Проводник = Новый ДиалогВыбораФайла(РежимДиалогаВыбораФайла.ВыборКаталога);
ЧтоБудетПосле = Новый ОписаниеОповещения("ПослеВыбораКаталога",ЭтотОбъект);
Проводник.Показать(ЧтоБудетПосле);
Проводник.Заголовок = "Выберите каталог";
```

КонецПроцедуры

&НаКлиенте
Процедура ПослеВыбораКаталога(ВыбранныеФайлы, ДополнительныеПараметры) Экспорт

```
Если ВыбранныеФайлы = Неопределено Тогда
    
    Возврат;
    
    КонецЕсли;

    ПутьКФайлу = ВыбранныеФайлы[0];     
        

КонецПроцедуры
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Answer (score 1):

Пример:

```
&НаСервереБезКонтекста
 Процедура УстановитьНаСервере(НовоеЗначениеКонстанты)
     Константы.КаталогЗагрузки.Установить(НовоеЗначениеКонстанты);
 КонецПроцедуры
 
 &НаКлиенте
 Процедура Установить(Команда)
     УстановитьНаСервере(ПутьККаталогу);
 КонецПроцедуры
```